# How to install mysql gem under OS X

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When installing the ruby `mysql` gem by doing:

```
sudo gem install mysql
```

Subsequent rails migrations still fail, with a message like:

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in /Users/guy/code/project)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix this issue (at the time of this question), you'll need to set an additional environment variable during installation.

For a 32-bit platform, do:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install mysql
```

For a 64-bit platform, do:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql
```

Once complete, your migrations should succeed (assuming no other factors were impeding the migrations).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the third time I've ended up here. Thanks for this.